# Application endpoint bypassing beanstalk endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am going live with my mobile application next week and have some confusion with my configurations. My architecture consists of Elastic beanstalk, CDN. My endpoint in Route53 will be alias of CloudFront, within Cloudfront there will be a distribution for load balancer of beanstalk.

Route53 > CloudFront > Loadbalancer >

With this method, I am bypassing the beanstalk endpoint provisioned by AWS, as the cloudfront distribution is linked directly with the load balancer of the beanstalk.

I was wondering if this the proper way or do I have any other option.

Comment: That's fine, the EB endpoint is just a pointer to the ELB.

Comment: You probably should not point directly to the elb.  If in the future you decide to rebuild the env or do a cname swap, you maybe forget about this configuration.  The elastic beanstalk name is just a pointer to your elb, why would you want to bypass it?